# My printer prints but the page is completely blank. Empty

Tags: printing, driver

I have a Xerox WorkCentre PE 16 (aka Samsung SCX 4216) (aka Lexmark X215).

I'm using MacOS 12 (Monterey).

I found the universal Samsung drivers from Apple website. They are not installable on macOS 12 but I found a way (using the app Pacifist).

I connect the old printer with USB cable. Add the printer using the installed driver.

The printer is installed.

I print something.

The print starts.

#### BUT!!!

But the page is completely blank. Empty. No sign. No char printed. Nothing.

The same printer works perfectly well if I (with the same USB cable) connect it to Windows or Linux PC.

**Why the empty page?**

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried the generic Postscript driver and/or the (HP) PCL driver that comes with macOS?

Comment: I don't know how to try it.

Comment: But why the paper is blank? Empty?

Comment: I tried with the PCL generic. When I install it the printer starts but when I print it doesn't print.

Comment: @FredHors The paper is probably blank because the renderer is probably crashing.  You found a way to force the driver on, but it doesn't actually work.

Comment: @Marc, thanks for your answer. I don't see any crash, I mean there is no sign, no error, no alert. Is there any error log in MacOs? Any idea how to fix this issue? A generic driver? I only need to print simple black & white papers...